# Loading 50 UITableviews on a Screen Asynchronously

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

Like the question said.

I tried `NSOperationQueues` but I am confused as to what to execute in the operation block. I tried the function `reloadData` to load in the operation queue but all the `UITableView`s appear at once.

I am using custom cells on the said `UITableView`s.

TIA

Comment: Did you try using GCD for this? You can use serial dispatch queues for this purpose.

Comment: Unless you have 50 table views all on screen at the same time, you are doing something wrong. You should probably have 50 datasource/cell delegates and one table view. Save the scroll position and simply swap out the data to transition between the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If your data loading is done on background threads you need to ensure that you return to the main thread before triggering any change to UI. So, when you call `reloadData`, make sure it runs on the main thread:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you, but the table views are loading fine. Just that they are taking an awful lot of time and they all appear at once on the page. I have 50 Tableviws on that view and I want each of them to load the data one by one. I tried adding "ReloadData" method of TableView to an operation queue with MaxConcurrentOperations set to 1 and runs in the background. Still no luck.  Will anything change if I add this line? Because TableView's delegate methods always get called on the main thread.

Comment: Your queue setup sounds ok, but each operation should reload the table view (on the main thread) before the next one starts.